# I have class Courses attached with 3 classes I want to display studydetails by selecting department & session lists

Tags: asp.net-mvc, full-text-search, dropdown

```
public class Courses
{
    [Key]
    public int Course_ID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Department")]
    public Department Departments { get; set; }
    public int Department_ID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Semester")]
    public Semester Semesters { get; set; }
    public int SemesterID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Session")]
    public SessionDetail SessionDetails { get; set; }
    public int SessionID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Course Title")]
    public string Course_Title { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Course Code")]
    public string Course_Code { get; set; }
    [Display(Name ="Credit Hours")]
    public string Cridth_Hours { get; set; }
}
```

This is my Class named Courses that is attatched with 3 other classes named Departments SessionDetail and Semester. I want that a view shows me the course details of a specific session and department of students form 2 dropdown lists of  department and session.

Comment: What software are you asking about?

Comment: I am asking about Asp.net MVC

Comment: Is this code in c#?

Comment: What have you tried? What doesn't work? What's broken?

Comment: Yes this is in C#. I want to search my courses list by using 2 drop down lists of Department and session